# Time series on syslogs

Tags: time-series

Is time series model suitable for network syslogs considering the fact the messages are sequential and the messages are outputted as a result of dependency between themselves which can range from normal notifications to alarms if there are.

Can the state of the art models like ARIMA be applied ?

What kind of questions can be answered with applying time series models on syslogs ?

Answer (score 0):

No, according to your description the syslog is not a time series data.

Time series data means to have a **numerical** value at each time stamps. For instance, if your log records the CPU usage (a number between 0 to 100%) then it is a time series data.

If you log is a sequence of text message, like the `/var/log/syslog` in Linux, then it is not a time series data.

Comment: Thank you for this! But what if the messages are transformed into their respective frequency counts, say hourly; would it be appropriate to use time series model? If not, so what kind of models can be used in forecasting with syslogs ?